# Attempting to create a matrix array from a file, but program returns two of the same matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, netbeans

Okay, the goal of the program is to add together two matrices that are filled by a file. My program creates and prints the first array just fine, but when I attempt to fill and print the second one, it just fills and reprints the first one. I can justify why, but I am not sure how to go about fixing it.

Here is the file

```
3 4

2 1 7 -10
0 5 -3 12
1 7 -2 -5

0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1
```

The 3 and 4 are just to determine the rows and columns, as you'll see in the code below. So the first array/matrix is:

```
 2 1 7 -10
 0 5 -3 12
 1 7 -2 -5
```

And the second

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Matrices {

    public static int[][] readMatrix(int rows, int columns, String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        rows = fileReader.nextInt();
        columns = fileReader.nextInt();
        int[][] result = new int[rows][columns];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                result[i][j] = fileReader.nextInt();

            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int columns = matrix[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
               System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And my driver:

```
public class MatricesDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name of file: ");
        String filename = keyboard.next();
        File file = new File(filename);
        int rows = 0;
        int columns = 0;

        int[][] a = Matrices.readMatrix(rows, columns, filename);
        int[][] b = Matrices.readMatrix(rows, columns, filename);

        Matrices.printMatrix(a);
        System.out.println();
        Matrices.printMatrix(b);
    }
}
```

The code works fine for filling and printing the first matrix, but fails to do the same on the second matrix. Here is the output:

```
Enter name of file: 
data/MAtrices.txt
2 1 7 -10 
0 5 -3 12 
1 7 -2 -5 

2 1 7 -10 
0 5 -3 12 
1 7 -2 -5
```

It just prints the first matrix again. How do I create the two separate matrices using the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that each matrices is being read from the right row number. Therefore, if you keep the record of row/column number then you'll be set:

```
class Matrices {
private Scanner fileReader;
private int rows;
private int columns;

public Matrices(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.fileReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    rows = fileReader.nextInt();
    columns = fileReader.nextInt();
}

public int[][] readMatrix() throws FileNotFoundException {

    int[][] result = new int[rows][columns];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            result[i][j] = fileReader.nextInt();

        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for ( int[] anArray : matrix ) {
        for ( int anInt : anArray ) {
            System.out.print(anInt+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

and `main` method would become:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name of file: ");
    String filename = keyboard.next();

    Matrices matrixReader = new Matrices(filename);
    int[][] a = matrixReader.readMatrix();
    int[][] b = matrixReader.readMatrix();

    Matrices.printMatrix(a);
    System.out.println();
    Matrices.printMatrix(b);
}
```

and the **OUTPUT** would be:

```
2 1 7 -10 
0 5 -3 12 
1 7 -2 -5 

0 1 2 3    
4 5 6 7 
8 9 0 1
```

Comment: Alright, that seems to work. But I also have another question. Is it possible for me two create two different sized 2D arrays with this method? So for example, the one above was adding two 3x4 matrices. What if I wanted to get the difference between two 2x2 arrays immediately after, from the same file? Is that possible?

Comment: You can do it since there would be a line before the two 2x2 matrices , specifying the row and column for upcoming matrices (i.e. `2 2`). You can implement a helper method which would scan next line and update the rows and columns for the next couple of matrices to be processed properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your read method to read and return two matrices!

Right now it keeps opening the file, reading the first entry only to return that. It shows only the first matrix because your current code simply stops instead of reading the data of the second matrix.

You could enhance your file format to include the number of matrices, too. And then you have to return an array of matrices instead of just one, simply by reading all information given in your input file.

But honestly, your code is pretty good as it is now, I would rather go with using multiple files and keeping exactly one matrix in each file.